# Why are the number of observations in an R dataframe more than what is in the CSV file?

Tags: python, mysql, r, pandas, csv

I have a file of sample data exported from a MySQL table that contains 99,977 rows.  When I import into R, it tells me that I have 101,942 observations of 49 variables.  Seeing as that is more, I also imported into a Pandas dataframe with Python and retrieved the same 99,977 rows and says that I have 48 columns which is what I have in the MySQL table.

I believe the extra column in R is "row.names" which I can see when I do `colnames(ds)`, but not sure.  I don't understand why I'm seeing 1,965 more observations in R.  Unless a record and an observation aren't the same?

**The code I'm using for R is:**

```
ds <- read.csv("/project/data/scenario_data.csv", quote = "", 
               row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

> nrow(ds)
[1] 101942
> ncol(ds)
[1] 49
```

**The Python Pandas code I'm using is:**

```
scenario_df = pd.read_csv('/project/data/scenario_data.csv')

index = scenario_df.index
len(index)
--> 99977

len(scenario_df.columns)
--> 48
```

I'd appreciate any info on why I'm seeing this.  Thanks very much for your assistance.

Comment: If you do a `wc` on the file, how many lines are in the CSV? I can't think of a way that R would have an `nrow()` value larger than the number of lines in the file (there are ways of getting fewer). It's probably going to be very difficult to say what's going on with a reproducible example, but i'm guessing it might be some sort of quoting/escaping issue. Maybe also try `readr::read_csv`

Comment: I opened it in Visual Editor and Excel.  Both showed the correct number of lines.

Comment: Are you sure you need to disable quoting altogether with `quote = ""`?